# Creating a test suite using Ruby minitest

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I'm moving my tests to the new ruby minitest library, and I am looking for the class that corresponds to the old Test::Unit::TestSuite class. All the examples I've found online show single test cases, but I've got:

```
require 'minitest/unit/testsuite'
require 'minitest/unit/ui/console/testrunner'

require 'tests/fs_session_test'
require 'tests/resource_test'
require 'tests/rest_session_test'
require 'tests/server_test'

class AllTests
  def self.suite
    suite = Test::Unit::TestSuite.new
    suite << FSSessionTest.suite
    suite << ResourceTest.suite
    suite << RESTSessionTest.suite
    suite << ServerTest.suite
  end
end

Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run(AllTests)
```

and I keep getting a LoadError on the testsuite require.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no `Test::Unit::TestSuite` in minitest. You have several options, assuming your tests look something like this:

```
require 'minitest/unit'
require 'minitest/autorun'

class FSSessionTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def test_the_truth
    assert true
  end
end
```

The vital part here is `require 'minitest/autorun'` which uses `at_exit` to run all tests it can find, just before the enclosing script exits. I find this to be the easiest way for running my test suites.

### Run tests with Rake

For example, you can create a `Rakefile` using [`Rake::TestTask`](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/TestTask.html) which runs all the tests in your `test/` directory:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = 'tests/**/*_test.rb'
end
```

Run the tests with

```
$ rake test
```

### Require tests in a Ruby file

If you frequently only need certain tests, you can also write a test script, something like

```
require './tests/fs_session_test'
require './tests/resource_test'
require './tests/rest_session_test'
require './tests/server_test'
```

You could also include `require 'minitest/autorun'` at the top of this file to ensure, the tests are run, but i do this at the top of every test file, anyway. Run the suite with

```
$ ruby test.rb
```

### Result

Both methods give you the same output, for example something like

```
Run options: --seed 5559

# Running tests:

....

Finished tests in 0.001909s, 2095.3379 tests/s, 2095.3379 assertions/s.

4 tests, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Because mintiest makes use of `at_exit`, there is really no need to group the tests before you run them. You never get the output of only one test. Unless, of course you run a test on its own, for example with

```
$ ruby tests/fs_session_test.rb 
Run options: --seed 43007

# Running tests:

.

Finished tests in 0.000672s, 1488.0952 tests/s, 1488.0952 assertions/s.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: This autorun thing seems interesting, but it doesn't seem to actually run the tests for me... I can do a puts on the first line of a test and it never prints it, and a puts outside the test class in the same file prints, so I know it's being loaded. How is autorun actually supposed to work?

Comment: For Ruby 2.0 I get the warning message "MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test."