# Minitest - A test suite with method-level granularity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, minitest, test-suite

After an upgrade, I'm finding the same several test methods failing, so I'd like to automate testing just those instead of all methods in all classes. I want to list each class-method pair (e.g. `TestBlogPosts.test_publish`, `TestUsers.test_signup`) and have them run together as a test suite. Either in a file or on the command-line, I don't really care.

I'm aware of [these techniques to run several entire classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311454/creating-a-test-suite-using-ruby-minitest), but I'm looking for finer granularity here. (Similar to what -n /pattern/ does on the command-line - to run a subset of test methods - but across multiple classes.)

Answer (score 1):

You could renounce `minitest/autorun` and call `Minitest.run` with your self defined test selection.

An example:

```
gem 'minitest'
require 'minitest'
#~ require 'minitest/autorun' ##No!

#Define Test cases. 
#The `puts`-statements are kind of logging which tests are executed.
class MyTest1 < MiniTest::Test
  def test_add
    puts "call %s.%s" % [self.class, __method__]
    assert_equal(2, 1+1)
  end
  def test_subtract
    puts "call %s.%s" % [self.class, __method__]
    assert_equal(0, 1-1)
  end
end
class MyTest2 < MiniTest::Test
  def test_add
    puts "call %s.%s" % [self.class, __method__]
    assert_equal(2, 1+1)
  end
  def test_subtract
    puts "call %s.%s" % [self.class, __method__]
    assert_equal(1, 1-1)  #will fail
  end
end

#Run two suites with defined test methods.
Minitest.run(%w{-n /MyTest1.test_subtract|MyTest2.test_add/})  #select two specific test method
```

The result:

```
Run options: -n "/MyTest1.test_subtract|MyTest2.test_add/" --seed 57971

# Running:

call MyTest2.test_add
.call MyTest1.test_subtract
.

Finished in 0.002313s, 864.6753 runs/s, 864.6753 assertions/s.

2 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

When you call the following test:

```
Minitest.run(%w{-n /MyTest1.test_subtract/})  #select onespecific test method
puts '=================='
Minitest.run(%w{-n /MyTest2.test_add/})  #select one specific test method
```

then you get

```
Run options: -n /MyTest1.test_subtract/ --seed 18834

# Running:

call MyTest1.test_subtract
.

Finished in 0.001959s, 510.4812 runs/s, 510.4812 assertions/s.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
==================
Run options: -n /MyTest2.test_add/ --seed 52720

# Running:

call MyTest2.test_add
.

Finished in 0.000886s, 1128.0825 runs/s, 1128.0825 assertions/s.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

The `Minitest.run` takes the same parameters you use from the command line. So you can use the `-n` option with your selection, e.g. `/MyTest1.test_subtract|MyTest2.test_add/`.

You could define different tasks or methods with different `Minitest.run`-definition to define your test suites.

Attention: 
No test file you load may contain a `require 'minitest/autorun'`.